# Catching an exception in Django

Tags: python, django, vue.js, nginx, gunicorn

I have been building an application using Django and Vuejs. The application using YouTube API to scrap for videos based on a few conditions that are set in the website that I am building. For some conditions I am getting a very weird error which I am not able to catch. What can be done to catch the error?
Refer the screenshot: The error occurs at the place where I am printing Error 1. So many different times of errors occur here and I am not able to catch it, so that I can display customized messages based on the error.

[Area where the error was found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VwCS.png)

Comment: Pleas don't post screenshoot of the code but the actual code. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.